# time_field is not working in firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In code:

```
<%= form_for(:hotel,:url=>{:controller=>'hotels',:action=>'update'}) do |f|%>
<%= f.time_field :from_time %>
```

This `time_field` is working fine in chrome but in case of firefox it's not working.I am not able to set time in it.Why this is happening?

Comment: I guess you are using an older version of firefox. Try this after updating your firefox browser.

Comment: I already have latest version of firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, FireFox doesn't support all HTML 5 features. For example `FireFox 19` doesn't support the `date`/`time` field.

Check here compatibility of your various browser versions which are supported `date`/`time` field.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

So, update your firefox browser and it will solved your issue. ;)

**OR**

You can use **Javascript** or **[Jquery UI](https://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/)** which will also solve your issue.

Comment: So, what should i do? Is there any other field i should use or i have to search for java script code